# Reading file formatted with C in C#

Tags: c#, c, file, formatted

I have a binary file, that was written in C, which contains a long stream of numbers.
First it contains subsequently 4 times an int (so the first 16 bytes are 4 ints) and then it contains doubles (I assume every 8 bytes a new double).

There are no spaces at any point or anything else. Now I need to read the data with C# but so far everything I tried simply didn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: For those unfamiliar with C is this saying that its a binary file rather than a text file? If so http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx may help... HAs useful methods like ReadInt32 and so on...

Comment: First I tried opening the file with a `FileStream` and using `fs.Read(byte[4], 0, 4)` to read the first four bytes into the array and then using `BitConverter.ToInt32(byte[4], int)` to convert it into an int.
I tried the same with a `StreamReader` using `char[4]` but that also didn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't it theoratically be a textfile as it was created using fprintf.

Comment: If the numbers are indeed printed with "%d%d%d%d%lf%lf..." (with no spaces) and the lengths of their decimal representation varies (i.e. different number of digits/number), they are hard if not impossible to separate.

Comment: I have to correct my code, I just checked with the one who programmed the written file and he gave me a wrong information about "%d%d%d%d%lf%lf...", it is indead a binary file and I can easily use the accepted answer.

Comment: deleted my answer based on your clarification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open("file", FileMode.Open)))
{
  int a = br.ReadInt32();
  int b = br.ReadInt32();
  int c = br.ReadInt32();
  int d = br.ReadInt32();
  double e = br.ReadDouble();
  double f = br.ReadDouble();
  ...
}
```

Comment: This would work with binary files, but not with `fprintf`, that outputs the numbers as text.

Comment: Because they are text files. To make it clear, lets say I give you this text "12345". If I tell you that this text is actually two integers joined together, would you be able to tell me whether I had joined 12 and 345 or 123 and 45? In this text file, the first byte of data will be character code of 1, second byte will be character code of 2, and so on. Or maybe two or more bytes per character according to encoding. But if it was a binary file and I had written integers 1 and 2345 in it, the first four bytes of data would have been 0x00000001 and next four bytes would have been 0x00000929.

Comment: The above comment is to answer your query that why would this code not work for files created with fprintf.